# Expo: "Something went wrong" immediately on start

Tags: qr-code, expo

I have used Expo a few times successfully before, but for a few days now, I am unable to get into the Expo App. Whenever I open it, I see the Expo icon for a few seconds up to even minutes, and then it redirects me to the blue "Something went wrong" screen, as if I had tried to open an app.

But I didn't! It doesn't even let me scan a QR code, it just always shows this error. If I click the back button in the app, it simply terminates. I have ensured that it is the latest version and already reinstalled it once.

Comment: Follow the fix here - [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58760712/how-to-fix-metro-bundler-process-exited-with-code-1) Worked for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like it somehow had locked itself onto an old, now non-existant server, and kept at it after reinstalling the app. Here is how I solved the problem:

In the metro bundler, choose connection type "Tunnel" and copy and send the URL to your phone. If you then click on it on your phone, it should redirect to the expo app. After that it got unstuck and I could finally use it normally with the QR code again!

Answer (score 0):

The tools sometimes do get locked into this state.

Close and restart all components (Expo cli, browser tabs and clients) making sure to:

- Kill any stray processes on the server (you need to check Activity Monitor / Process Explorer or similar depending on your platform)
- Force quit all client devices and simulators using the correct method for each platform. To verify that the client process has actually been killed, check that the app splash screen is displayed for a short while when invoking it.
- Clear the Expo cache when starting again: `$ expo start --clear`

Comment: This happened without my laptop (on which the server runs) even being on, so the first and third points do not apply. It was not solved by force-quitting or even re-installing the expo app either.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Solved it by going to the left sidebar in the Metro Bundler and sending a link via email!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many of the solutions and only one worked for me (which i found trying random things).  I already had 'allow display over other apps' turned on (Android/OnePlus 6t) and didn't think it had anything to do with that.  But I tried this...

Close the Expo app, go the the app settings and turn off 'allow display over other apps', open the expo app and [when prompted] turn on 'allow display over other apps' again.

That seems to work in my case - at least until the next time.