# How to fix Metro Bundler process exited with code 1

Tags: react-native, expo, metro-bundler

How to fix Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
Metro 'Bundler' process exited with code 1

```
Error: Metro  'Bundler' process exited with code 1
    at 'ChildProcess' .<anonymous> (C:\@expo\xdl@56.6.0\'src'\Project.ts:1841:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Process.ChildProcess._    handle.onexit (internal/child_ 
    process.js:272:12)
 ERR! code     ELIFECYCLE
 ERR! err no 1
 ERR! @ start: `expo start`
 ERR! Exit status 1
 ERR!
 ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

 ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 ERR!     C:\Users\Pranav\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-08T04_33_07_234Z-debug.log
```

Comment: how to solve  ERROR : Metro Bundler process exited with code 1

Answer (score 38):

If you are running on windows you can try the solutions provided in this thread on github.

Solution from github that seems to work:

```
Got this issue today on windows, but don't need to downgrade node, just as discussed on stackoverflow just need to change some hashes on your project:

\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js

var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

change to:

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/1074

Comment: Nice one, Thanks bro

Comment: Many thanks. Why this is not accepted as an answer?

Comment: error still occurs bro `error: unknown option `--assetExts'

Metro Bundler process exited with code 1`

Comment: a very big thanks Dagur, you saved me. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is a problem with the version (12.13.1) of node js. It works fine with older version 12.9.1.

I had a similar problem, so I uninstalled this version and installed the older version. This solved metro bundler problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is essentially the same answer as that posted by YAcine Mathurin over a week ago.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by simply deleting the folder:
**C:\Users\bunty\AppData\Roaming\npm**  and delete the npm folder.
and type the command **npm install -g expo-cli** in cmd(administrator).
if still it didn't work try using lower version of node(12.9.0).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, and fixed it by decreasing my nodejs version from <strike>12.13.1</strike> to **12.9.1**

Have the github thread for more details:
https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/1074

Comment: @Rohan Devaki uninstall your current version, restart your computer then choose of those releases on https://nodejs.org/dist/ to install. I'm on windows so I do use corresponding release of extension msi  for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in wsl2. it started to happen after installing a new extension. But just removing the extension did not do the job.

I had to delete the .vscode-server folder and then reload vscode